# Неверно отображается список python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
items = [[i + j for i in range(10)] for j in range(20)]
print(items)
```

Написал код, чтобы выводил [[0 .. 9],[10 .. 19] ... ]

А по итогу заполняется [[0 ..9], [1 .. 10] ...

Что не так у меня?

Comment: Лучше не называйте переменные именами [встроенных функций](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions), таких как `list`, а то не сможете ими пользоваться, например `print(list("1234"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
items = [[i + j * 10 for i in range(10)] for j in range(20)]
```

или

```
items = [list(range(i, i + 10)) for i in range(0, 200, 10)]
```

Comment: Ого, спасибо!!!